# Bootstrap 3 won't recognize the .col-#-# class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap only recognizes the span1-span12 classes but not the col-#-# classes! Meaning, if have 3 divs with the span4 class, my row will be divided into 3 divs. If I use the col-md-4 class, all 3 divs will appear as stacked no matter what. Anyone have an idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Want to post your HMTL?

Comment: spanX is for BT2 , col-x-x is for BT3 ... You don't have the good version of BT

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're referencing Bootstrap 3 if you want to use `col-*-*`

- `span*` are for Bootstrap 2
- `col-*-*` are for Bootstrap 3

Here is a useful [What's New in Bootstrap 3](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide) guide to see all of the differences between 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap 2: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

If you want to use col-#-# classes, you need to use Bootstrap 3: http://getbootstrap.com/

Bootstrap 3 scaffolding: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid